# Will custom headers in a request will be removed in aws by loadbalancer or any policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-application-load-balancer

I have created an API authorization system for accessing data with an API KEY in the server . I created a custom-header 'company-api-key' for transferring the key.
But the following header was not able to access from server in AWS.

Will custom headers in a request will be removed in AWS by loadbalancer or any policies